# Rogue Process Filling up Connections in Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, database-connection, connection

Last week we updated our DB Password and ever since after every db bounce the connections are getting filled up. 
We have 20+ schema and connections to only one Schema gets filled up. Nothing shows up in the sessions. There can be old apps accessing our database with old password and filling up connections.

How to identify how many processes are trying to connect to DB server and how many are failed.

Every time we bounce our db servers connections go through post 1hr no one else can make new connections.

Comment: What sort of connections are we talking here? Dedicated? Connection Pooling?

Answer (score 0):

BTW: in our company, we have LOGON and LOGOFF triggers which persist the session connect and disconnect information.

It is quite possible that what you are seeing are recursive sessions created by Oracle when it needs to parse SQL statements [usually not a performance problem, but processes parameter may need to be increased]: ...

for example 1, high values for dynamic_sampling cause more recursive SQL to be generated ;

example 2: I have seen a situation for this application of excessive hard parsing; this will drive up the process count as hard parsing will require new processes to execute parse related recursive SQL (increased the processes parameter in this case since it was a vendor app).  Since your issue is related to the bounce, it could be that the app startup requires a lot of parsing.

Example 3:
“Session Leaking” Root Cause Analysis:
Problem Summary: We observed periods where many sessions being created, without a clear understanding of what part of the application is creating them and why.
RCA Approach:  Since the  DB doesn't persist inactive sessions, I monitored the situation by manually snapshotting v$session.
Analysis:
   I noticed a pattern where multiple sessions have the same process#.
   As per Oracle doc’s, these sessions are recursive sessions created by oracle under an originating process which needs to do recursive SQL to satisfy the query (at parse level).  They go away when the process that created them is done and exits.
   If the process is long running, then they will stay around inactive until it is done.
   These recursive sessions don't count against your session limit and the inactive sessions are in an idle wait event and not consuming resources. 
   The recursive session are most certainly a result of recursive SQL needed by the optimizer where optimizer stats are missing (as is the case with GTT’s) and the initialization parameter setting of 4 for optimizer_dynamic_sampling .
   The 50,000 sessions in an hour that we saw the  other day is likely a result of a couple thousand select statements running (I’ve personally counted 20 recursive sessions per query, but this number can vary).
   The ADDM report showed that the impact is not much:
Finding 4: Session Connect and Disconnect
Impact is .3 [average] active sessions, 6.27% of total activity [currently on the instance]. 
Average Active Sessions is a measure of database load (values approaching CPU count would be considered high).  Your instance can handle up to 32 active sessions, so the impact is about 1/100th of the capacity.